# If you have multiple small pcbs in a single chassis, what is the naming convention for components?

Tags: best-practice

ie, on board 1 do you name resistors R1-R10, then on board 2 name them R1-R10 also?

Or do you name resistors R1-R10 on board 1, R11-R20 on board 2, etc?

What is the convention or best practice?

Comment: I don't think there is a best practice or convention. Each PCBA will typically have its own BOM anyway. But it is reasonable to use different ranges of numbers for different PCBA's. I would suggest 1-99, 101-100, etc. If you ever run out of numbers that are in range for that PCB, then it will get really ugly and confusing.

Comment: I would just give the boards an ID, that way you can say something like "B2-R1" to refer to "board 2, resistor 1". If they are identical boards, just refer to them by slot. I wouldn't change the silkscreen or BOM for the sake of being able to use the same PCB in different positions.

Comment: Usually each board is independent... With its own part number, BOM, docs etc...

Comment: Are the boards panelized in a group or groups, or are they assembled independently?

Comment: Are the boards sharing a schematic and/or BOM, or is each board being designed as a completely independent unit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen it done R100-R199 on board 1, R200-R299 on board 2 etc...

Comment: Thank you! I was honestly thinking about just numbering them starting at 1 and going up from there, across all boards, glad I asked here

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard convention, but I personally go for R100-199 for 1st PCB, R200-299 for 2nd ... in my designs.

Another approach I've seen in a 4-PCB product was like RA1-RA999, RB1-RB999 ...